# Find non-existing ID's using SELECT NOT IN?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of ID's, comma separated stored as string.

123,456,789

I was previously using something like this to pull data for each row in the database where each ID was present:

```
SELECT id, name FROM line_item WHERE id IN (123,456,789)
```

However, I want to only determine the ID's where they do not exist in the database. E.g. check the table to return all ID's provided that do not exist in the DB.

I tried `NOT IN` assuming it would work, but of course, all I got was every ID that did not match my sample, which was massive (thousands of rows, small number of ID's that we typically need to check for).

```
SELECT id FROM line_item WHERE id NOT IN (123,456,789)
```

For example:

Table: ID

```
111
222
333
444
555
777
999
```

String:

```
111,222,666,888,999
```

Query should return:

```
666,888
```

Using MySQL, can I find those values not present without using PHP.

Comment: I don't understand - "I want to only determine the ID's where they do not exist in the database" - do you mean you're looking in your database to find the data which is not there? Or do you want to find gaps in the sequence numbers?

Comment: Could you be more clear on why your `NOT IN` version didn't work?  To me, it sounds like what you're expecting is what you got when you tried `NOT IN` but at the same time you said that was "huge".

Comment: Since they don't exist, I suppose you would have to upper bound it somewhere (ie 1,000,000) and then select all records. Then loop through each record and remove it from your array of 1,000,000 or something similar. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Do you have another table / data source where the ids you want to select exist?

Comment: I've clarified the question a little. @symcbean - the first one - show me ID's not present at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create additional table populated with desired `id` values, and use query with LEFT JOIN and WHERE clauses -

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table(id INT);
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES(123),(456),(789);

SELECT t1.id FROM temp_table t1
  LEFT JOIN line_item t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Another variant:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM (SELECT 123 id UNION SELECT 456 UNION SELECT 789) t1
  LEFT JOIN line_item t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Be sure to use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE, so that the table is dropped when the connection is closed automagically.

Comment: @fiskfisk Yes, of course. Also, for this purpose SELECT...UNION SELECT... query may be used.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know you could create temp tables. I'll give it a try - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN` will take the values in the parentheses and cause the query to, as you said, give you all other ids.

I do not know if there is a way to do this with several numbers simultaneously - but this is how you could do it with one:

```
SELECT id, name, description
FROM line_item
WHERE 1 NOT IN (SELECT id FROM line_item) // Replace 1 with your numbers in a loop
```

Answer (score 0):

On Postgresql you can use the `generate_series(i,j)` function. For example to find the non-existent integers in the `id` column you can write:

```
select i from generate_series(
    (select min(id) from line_item),(select max(id) from line_item)
) as i 
where i not in (select id from line_item);
```

If you want to use this query to find the first available integer to use as an id, you can use this query:

```
select min(i) from generate_series(
    (select min(id) from line_item),(select max(id) from line_item)+1
) as i 
where i not in (select id from line_item);
```